# Any opened supermarket near?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

I want to know if this sentence is correct:

> Are there any opened supermarket near?

If I want to place "Do you know" *before* the question, which is preferred?

> - Do you know if are there any opened supermarket near?
> - Do you know if there are any opened supermarket near?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your sentence(s) worth reviewing.

First, verbs should agree in number with the subject. *There* is not the subject; it stands in for *supermarket* which is singular.

> <s>Are</s> **Is** there <s>any</s> **an** open(ed) supermarket near? or
>   Are there any open(ed) supermarket**s** near?

Second, near is close to but not synonymous with *nearby*. Nearby is a place. *Near* needs an object (the object of the preposition): near here/near us/near you?

*Do you know if* does modify the structure of the previous question (it forms the question instead of the verb-before-subject form, so the regular form must be used.

> Do you know if there are any open(ed) supermarket**s** nearby?

However, if you use only *Do you know*, without the *if*, you need not change the order; *do you know* acts like an interjection of sorts:

Do you know, are there any opened supermarkets nearby?
Are there any opened supermarkets nearby, do you know?

Comment: 'opened' is odd here, you really should just say 'open'

Comment: @curiousdannii - that might be cultural, which is why I placed it in parentheses.

Comment: Even if it is cultural, I don't believe you can go wrong with "open". "Opened" does sound odd. Unless it's an edge case like you know that they were building the new supermarket, but you don't know if it has opened yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any opened supermarket near?

Is definitely *incorrect*, simply because the verb (*are*) is plural, whereas the subject (*supermarket*) is singular.

Also, I would use *nearby* instead of *near* in this case, although that might be a detail.

Two correct options are:

> Is there any opened supermarket nearby?
>   Are there any opened supermarkets nearby?

As for the second question, your second sentence is correct as to the order of the words:

> Do you know if there are any opened supermarkets nearby?